# What fantasy movie is this quote from?

Tags: story-identification, movie, quotes

> with one cherry you may pass to the world behind the glass

I  remember the girl moves into her grandmas house and she finds an old standing mirror. Behind the mirror, stuck to it, there are some cherries and the quote. She uses it to get through the mirror into a different world.

Comment: Where did you watch this, where, and in what language?

Comment: it was like 20 years ago and I remember it in English so I assume that is the original language

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The movie might be [Magic In The Mirror (1996)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116959/):

A little girl's imaginary friends come to life when she goes through her great-grandmother's antique mirror, a la Alice, after she sees it glowing. The line you are remembering is at 01 hour 10 minutes of the film.

> "With one berry you may pass, inside the world behind the glass."

Comment: You might want to add a brief transcription

Comment: And here I was still looking for whether there were cherries... :)

Comment: oh my God, this is it, latter in the movie someone will read the quote from behind the mirror. I have spent years looking for this movie, obviously in the wrong places, since I got my answer really fast here. Thank you so much.

Comment: What's the quote though?

Comment: @Valorum "With one berry you may pass, to the world behind the glass"